# Button to Launch Multiple URLs

Tags: button, url

I have created a button on the opportunity that launches a URL in a new window (i.e. https://test.com/launch/{!Opportunity.Contact_Name__c}).

1. Is there a way instead of just launching a URL associated with the primary contact to launch multiple URLs, one for each of the contracts associated with the opportunity?
2. Is there a way I can launch a URL in a new window using a checkbox field update on the Contact Record.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Additional Question: Is there a way I can "click" on a hyperlink using a workflow rule / process builder?

Comment: Workfllow rule process builder runs even if there is no UI. So your additional question might not be possible